# How do I create an init method for a struct which is only visible in tests?

Tags: swift, swift-extensions

I want to create an init method for my struct with a bunch of default values for use in unit tests. I don't want the main module to be able to see this init method.

I thought I could simply create an extension of my struct in my test class's file, but this doesn't work:

Foo.swift (in app target):

```
public struct Foo {

    public let bar: Int

    public init(colour: String) {
        self.bar = colour == "Green" ? 0 : 1
    }

}
```

FooExtension.swift (in test target):

```
extension Foo {

    public init(bar: Int = 42) {
        self.bar = bar
    }

}
```

*Note the non-default initializer in the main file, so the Swift compiler does not automatically create the memberwise initializer for me. Maybe this has something to do with the problem, maybe not.*

The Swift compiler complains `Cannot assign to 'bar' in 'self'`. But when I copy that init method into the original definition of my `Foo` struct in my main target, it works fine. I get the same results with or without the default parameter values.

Is this a Swift compiler bug or something to do with defining extensions in one module for structs defined in another? Everything works fine when I try and replicate this in a Playground.

I am using Swift 1.2 with Xcode Version 6.4 (6E35b)

Comment: It works if the property is declared as `public var`, but not `public let`. It looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Ah, good point, I didn't specify that—it's intended to be an immutable struct and all the properties are `let`.

Comment: @RobertAtkins: could you please put your code in here.  I just tried similar thing (having parametrised `init(...)` in the main app and extending the type with `init()` assigning pre-defined values to `let`-properties in the test-class) and that worked fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've had a response to the radar I filed on this; what I'm asking for is now [explicitly disallowed](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0189-restrict-cross-module-struct-initializers.md).

Answer (score 2):

Create an initializer (init method) in a struct that is only visible in tests by using the @testable attribute.

e.g.

```
struct MyStruct {
    let property: Int
    
    init(property: Int) {
        self.property = property
    }
}

@testable import MyModule

class MyStructTests: XCTestCase {
    func testInit() {
        let myStruct = MyStruct(property: 123)
        XCTAssertEqual(myStruct.property, 123)
    }
}
```